# Where are my log files?

Tags: logs

I ran `less /var/log/messages` and got the output

```
/var/log/messages: No such file or directory
```

How can I either find them or set up error handling? Is there an app that can notify me of errors?

I'm using Lubuntu 15.04.

I found [how to receive email alerts of hardware problems](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-server-predicting-hardware-failure.html). Please tell me if the script would still work.

Comment: A little more effort searching over the internet can be great.

Comment: I don't like your style of question. First part would be solved easily by Google and second part is not really a question, more an invitation to do your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As krt pointed out

the messages equivalent in Debian based systems is

```
$ less /var/log/syslog
```

and since 15.04 systemd is installed, so you can use `journalctl` to see the logs. Create directory `/var/log/journal` to get persistent logs.

Comment: How Can I install journalctl?

Answer (score 5):

Lubuntu dosen't use `messages`, it uses `syslog`. Do this instead:

```
$ less /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsyslogd & edit /etc/rsyslog.conf, & make any facility redirect to any file you want, check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40533/lubuntu-12-04-syslog-to-custom-file-not-var-log-syslog-but-var-log-mylog)!.

man syslog
man rsyslogd

for more options